# Load document.ready onload of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller

I need to execute function on element load (on .cshtml page). (lets say it's a div element).

I did:

```
$('#MyDiv').ready(function () {
alert('Div loaded');
});
```

The problem is that the alert jumps always. When the javascript code itself loaded.
I did:

```
 $('#MyDiv').load(function () {
    alert('Div loaded');
    });
```

And the alert never jumps.

Solution?

Comment: The `ready()` method is meant to be used only with the `document` element. The `load()` method when applied to a `div` element is treated as an AJAX request. See [jQuery load() as an AJAX method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and [jQuery load() as an event method](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot detect when an element is "ready" in the same way as you can with `$(document).ready()`.

What you *can* do is add a script tag after your element that will run after your element is rendered by the browser:

```
<div> * content * </div>
<script>
doSomething();
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately - my purpose is to clean my HTML from the javascript code and move it to a .js file. add <script> element will disrupt my purpose.

Comment: Mike C's answer is probably your best bet then. Wait until the entire document is ready and then alert the elements you want.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this, perhaps it is wrong:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  alert('Div Ready or Document Loaded, or whatever');

  ..all kinds of other jquery inside this function..

});
```